# Merging objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to merge the objects recursively.

what I have

```
arrayOfObjects = [{a1:{aa:k1}},{a1:{ab:k2}},{a1:{ac:k3}},{a1:{aa:k4}},{a1:{ab:k5}}];
```

what I need is

```
{a1:{aa:k1,ab:k2,ac:k3,aa:k4,ab:k5}}
```

I made a function

```
function merg(array){
    value = {};
    if(array.length>0){
       $.each(array, function (i) {
           value = $.extend(true,{},value,array[i]);
       });
    }
    return value;
};

console.log(merg(arrayOfObjects));
```

what I get is

```
{a1:{aa:k1,ab:k2,ac:k3}}
```

aa:k4,ab:k5 are missing(may due to same key value )

if the deep merge is false I get only one value

```
value = $.extend({},value,array[i]);
{a1:{aa:k1}}
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an object. Objects are maps whose keys are unique. You could merge duplicate keys into arrays, but not duplicates keys twice. It's senseless, ask yourself how do you expect to access `a1.aa`. Which value do you expect to get, is it k1 or k4? How do you differ them?

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of Symbols,

```js
var arr = [{a1:{aa:'k1'}},{a1:{ab:'k2'}},{a1:{ac:'k3'}},{a1:{aa:'k4'}},{a1:{ab:'k5'}}];;

var op = {};

var result = {};

var globalKey;

arr.forEach((ar) => {
    var [key, value] = Object.entries(ar)[0];
    globalKey = key;
    var [innerKey, innerValue] = Object.entries(value)[0];
    op[Symbol(innerKey)] = innerValue;
});

result[globalKey] = op;

console.log(result);
```